# Sprite not moving with PathModifier using Andengine

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper

I am build a live wallpaper and all I would like is for, right now, a simple sprite to move right and that's all. I have no animation for the sprite. The wallpaper loads and I see the sprite but it's just not moving.
I've implemented the PathModifer and 0 errors, I've checked my code to numerous examples and posts and I just cannot figure out why it is not moving.

Here is my entire class:

```
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.LoopEntityModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.IPathModifierListener;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.Path;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.extension.ui.livewallpaper.BaseLiveWallpaperService;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.AccelerationData;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.IAccelerationListener;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;
import org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseSineInOut;

public class LiveWallpaperService extends BaseLiveWallpaperService implements IAccelerationListener{

//================================================================================
//  Fields
//================================================================================

    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 854;

    private Scene mScene;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas grass;
    private ITextureRegion yourTextureRegion;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas house;
    private ITextureRegion houseRegion;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas cloud1;
    private ITextureRegion cloud1Region;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
      Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
              EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true,
                      ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                              CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
              return options;

     }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
            throws Exception {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        this.grass = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1024, 512, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        yourTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.grass, this, "bglwp.png", 0, 0);
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.grass);

        this.cloud1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 128, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        cloud1Region = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.cloud1, this, "clld1.png", 0, 0);
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.cloud1);

        this.house = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 512, 512, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        houseRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.house, this, "front.png", 0, 0);
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.house);


        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        final float x = CAMERA_WIDTH / 2 - yourTextureRegion.getWidth() /2;
        final float y = CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2 - yourTextureRegion.getHeight() /2;
        final float xx = CAMERA_WIDTH / 2 - houseRegion.getWidth() /2;
        final float yy = CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2 - houseRegion.getHeight() /2;

         mScene= new Scene();
         mScene.setBackground(new Background(0.3294117f, 0.788235f, 0.909803f));
         Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(x - 80, y + 171, this.yourTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         mScene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);

         Sprite foregroundSprite = new Sprite(xx + 10, yy + 80, this.houseRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         mScene.attachChild(foregroundSprite);

         Sprite cloud1Sprite = new Sprite( 100, 100, this.cloud1Region, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

         final Path path = new Path(2).to(200, 200).to(20, 20);

         cloud1Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(
                 new PathModifier(5, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
                    Debug.d("onPathStarted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointStarted(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        IEntity pEntity, int pWaypointIndex) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointFinished(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        IEntity pEntity, int pWaypointIndex) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathFinished(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        IEntity pEntity) {
                }
                 }, EaseSineInOut.getInstance())));

         mScene.attachChild(cloud1Sprite);
         pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mScene);
         }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
            OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Any help anyone has would be most appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is this GLES1? Because your Path Modifier constructor arguments dont match what I have in GLES2 
new PathModifier(30, path, null, new IPathModifierListener()

Comment: It's GLES 2, I've removed the (new LoopEntityModifier and it still does the exact same thing.

Comment: Okay - I copied down your code and built it. Updated my answer below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. It runs on my device. The problem seems to be its moving to little and too slow to easily notice. Try changing your duration from 30 to 5.

```
new PathModifier(5, path, null, new IPathModifierListener();
```

I also spaced out the path coordinates more to make the move more noticeable.

```
 final Path path = new Path(2).to(200, 200).to(0, 0);
```

Now its clearly moving.

Here is my full class:

```
package com.example.andenginetestbed;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.adt.io.in.IInputStreamOpener;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;
import org.andengine.util.modifier.ease.EaseSineInOut;

import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.LoopEntityModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.IPathModifierListener;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.PathModifier.Path;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class TestBed extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private ITexture mTexture;
    private ITextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_bed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_bed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources() {
        try {
            this.mTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("tank.png");
                }
            });

            this.mTexture.load();
            this.mFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mTexture);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Sprite> placedSprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        /* Calculate the coordinates for the face, so its centered on the camera. */
        final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;

        final Sprite bigTank = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(bigTank);

        final Sprite smallTank = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        smallTank.setScaleCenter(smallTank.getWidth()/2, smallTank.getHeight()/2 );
        smallTank.setScale(0.667f);
        smallTank.setRotationCenter(smallTank.getWidthScaled() / 2,
        smallTank.getHeightScaled() / 2);
        smallTank.setRotation(45);
        scene.attachChild(smallTank);

         final Sprite cloud1Sprite = smallTank;

         final Path path = new Path(2).to(200, 200).to(0, 0);

         cloud1Sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(
                 new PathModifier(10, path, new IPathModifierListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {
                    Debug.d("onPathStarted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointStarted(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        IEntity pEntity, int pWaypointIndex) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointFinished(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        IEntity pEntity, int pWaypointIndex) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathFinished(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                        IEntity pEntity) {
                }
                 }, EaseSineInOut.getInstance())));
        return scene;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for testing it for me. It does not move on my device at all, perhaps it is that. I'll try and find another device to test with. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the entire class? Mine's not a wallpaper, but a BaseGameActivity.

Comment: Sure, I think it's too long for a comment though. Should I edit my question?

Comment: please. If I could figure out how to go to chat we could do that. Sometimes a button pops up here.

Comment: My rep is too low to chat :(

Comment: D'oh. Just trying to set this up as a live wallpaper to test. I'll be removing the foreground and bg. Just the cloud.

Comment: Well I'll be danged. As a live wallpaper, nothing! You have identified a bug in the engine, i think. Sorry - that's really not much help at all.

Comment: Oh goodness, it really seems to be a bug? So much time spent trying to figure out what I did wrong! I appreciate everything you've done. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can check it out yourself. The code I have above is a BaseGameActivity, and you code runs. Maybe try using a MoveModifier, or simply setPosition on your sprite in the update function of the LiveWallpaper. Your path seems pretty simple.

Comment: That position was just to test really, all I need it to do is move right, only right, nothing fancy.

Comment: Then I think you're in luck, you wont need move modifiers at all. If you want to make it ease in and out as it reaches the end, you can Multilply a counter times Math.sin(counter) * range of motion - and that will oscillate the object gently back and forth.

Comment: What do you mean I won't need move modifiers? How else could I have it move. Sorry if I wasn't clear I need it to move right, get to the end, the reset back to start position and then go right and repeat.

I was looking into MoveModifier

Comment: Use cloud.setPosition(x, y) and manage the position yourself each frame. You set the LiveWallpaperService class as the registeredUpdateHandler(this). And implement iUpdateHandler in your class. And voila! You can update the position of your cloud each frame.

Comment: I can't seem to get MoveModifier to work either... And I'm confused with setPosition, it seems I would need to walk the sprite manually across the screen? Because from what I gather setPosition is basically for teleporting a sprite. I wish this wasn't so difficult

Comment: The difference between teleporting and moving is one of speed. Take a look at this example from the andengine examples. 
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/MovingBallExample.java

Comment: Hi! Well I figured out the main issue, I needed this in OnPopulatescene

pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

So simple, and blind oversight that took me way too long to realize.

Comment: Did that fix the original issue with the EntityModifiers?

Comment: Yes, it's because the method wasn't closing so the engine was just sitting there waiting for something to happen in OnPopulateScene. A silly oversight, thank you for all of your help!